# How to define case class with a list of tuples and access the tuples in scala

Tags: scala, case-class

I have a case class with a parameter a which is a list of int tuple. I want to iterate over a and define operations on a.

I have tried the following:

```
case class XType (a: List[(Int, Int)]) {
 for (x <- a) {
  assert(x._2 >= 0)
 }
 def op(): XType = {
  for ( x <- XType(a))
    yield (x._1, x._2)
  }
}
```

However, I am getting the error:

> "Value map is not a member of XType."

How can I access the integers of tuples and define operations on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into an issue with `for` comprehensions, which are really another way of expressing things like `foreach` and `map` (and `flatMap` and `withFilter`/`filter`). See [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) and [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html#translating-for-comprehensions) for more explanation.

Your first `for` comprehension (the one with asserts) is equivalent to

```
a.foreach(x => assert(x._2 >= 0))
```

`a` is a `List`, `x` is an `(Int, Int)`, everything's good.

However, the second on (in `op`) translates to

```
XType(a).map(x => x)
```

which doesn't make sense--`XType` doesn't know what to do with `map`, like the error said.

An instance of `XType` refers to its `a` as simply `a` (or `this.a`), so `a.map(x => x)` would be just fine in `op` (and then turn the result into a new `XType`).

As a general rule, `for` comprehensions are handy for nested `map`s (or `flatMap`s or whatever), rather than as a 1-1 equivalent for `for` loops in other languages--just use `map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the tuple list by:

```
def op(): XType = {
  XType(a.map(...))
}
```